# Array js dando erro

Tags: javascript

Tenho o seguinte `javaScript`:

```
  var imagem = [];

  for (i = 0; i < quantasImagens; i++) {    

      tMin = t + tempoTransicao;
      tMax = t + tamanhoIntervalos; 
      t+=tamanhoIntervalos;

      if(i==0) tMin=0;
      if(i==quantasImagens) tMax=100;         


      imagem[i][0] = tMin + "% { margin-left:-" + tempoImagens + "%};";
      imagem[i][1] = tMax + "% { margin-left:-" + tempoImagens + "%};";

      tempoImagens+=100;

  }

  for (po=0; po<imagem.length; i++) {
      document.write(imagem[i][0]);
      document.write("<br />");
      document.write(imagem[i][1]);
      document.write("<br />");
      document.write("<br />");
  }
```

quando o for faz a segundo ciclo, dá erro na linha:

```
      imagem[i][0] = tMin + "% { margin-left:-" + tempoImagens + "%};";
```

Dizendo que o índice 0 não existe.

Onde estou errando?

Comment: var imagem = []; Está errado? Obs.: já tentei new Array()

Comment: Dentro de cada `imagem[i]` tem outra array que você tb não declarou. Dentro do loop.

Comment: Mas é isso que estou pedindo. Que me ensine a declarar Já fiz [[]] também não deu certo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se cada item da array de imagens também for um array, você precisa declará-los dentro do seu loop:

```
imagem[i] = [];
imagem[i].push(tMin + "% { margin-left:-" + tempoImagens + "%};");
imagem[i].push(tMax + "% { margin-left:-" + tempoImagens + "%};");
```

Repare que estou usando `push` em vez de atribuir diretamente a cada índice. Funciona também do jeito que você fez, mas prefiro o push por ser o jeito padrão de inserir itens em arrays.

Comment: De fato funcionou. Obrigado! Agora aprendi.